# Netbeans 8 shortcuts for showing parameters and showing return value

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the shortcut in Netbeans 8 for showing a method's parameters and a method's return value?

Comment: Crtl+Space shows the JavaDoc of the method the cursor is currently placed at.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to **`Ctrl + Space`** (code completion) you can use these shortcuts:

- **`Ctrl + P`**: Shows the method parameters
- **`Ctrl + Shift + Space`**: Shows documentation

Comment: I believe your 1st point isn't correct(2nd is absolutely fine). In my case, the method doesn't show any parameter/doesn't have any effect,,, except that they point to their definition in the file when Ctrl-clicked(NetBeans IDE 8.0.2).

Comment: What language have you tested? I'm using `ctrl + p` on java, c and c++ without error (I'm currently on 8.1).